# Issue with cloning div and appending to DOM with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm retrieving some info from a server in JSON format using AJAX GET call, after this I clone a `div` hidden inside my DOM and append it to my `div`s container, the `div` is cloned and appended correctly, but the data is not correctly printed and this is the result I get:

[image: HTML document result]

However if I create an HTML `template` inside my `each` function, it works.  I clone the `div` instead to avoid cluttering my `success` function.

My jQuery code, where I clone and append the `div` and the hidden `template` in my DOM:

```js
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
console.log(data.success);

$.each(data.starters, function(index, item) {
  /*
  var menu_row_1 = '<div class="section_menu_bahi_row_container" style="">'; 
  menu_row_1 += '<span class="section_menu_bahi_row_name" style="">' + item.name + '</span>';
  menu_row_1 += '<span class="section_menu_bahi_row_half" style="">' + item.half + '</span>';
  menu_row_1 += '<span class="section_menu_bahi_row_full" style="">' + item.full + '</span>';
  menu_row_1 += '</div>';
   
  var menu_row_2 =  '<div class="section_menu_mada_page_row_container" style="">';
  menu_row_2 += '<span class="section_menu_mada_page_row_name" style="">' + item.name + '</span>';
  menu_row_2 += '<span class="section_menu_mada_page_row_half" style="">' + item.half + '</span>';
  menu_row_2 += '<span class="section_menu_mada_page_row_full" style="">' + item.full + '</span>';
  menu_row_2 += '</div>';
  */
  
  var menu_row = $('.section_menu_mada_page_row_container').clone();
  $(".menu_container[data-link='starters']").append(menu_row);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section style="width:100%; height:auto; visibility:hidden;">
  <div class="section_menu_mada_page_row_container" style="">
    <span class="section_menu_mada_page_row_name" style="">' + item.name + '</span>
    <span class="section_menu_mada_page_row_half" style="">' + item.half + '</span>
    <span class="section_menu_mada_page_row_full" style="">' + item.full + '</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you can use jquery template for this. here is the link for jquery template. https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery-tmpl/ , this will make your work very easy

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery template for this. Here is the link of the [jQuery template on GitHub](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.success);

  var starters_data = data.starters;
  var markup = "<div class=\"section_menu_mada_page_row_container\"><span class=\"section_menu_mada_page_row_name\">{name}</span><span class=\"section_menu_mada_page_row_half\">{half}</span><span class=\"section_menu_mada_page_row_full\">{full}</span></div>";

  $.template("meneRowTemplate", markup);
  $.tmpl("meneRowTemplate", starters_data).appendTo(".menu_container[data-link='starters']");
});
```

Comment: uhmm I'll take a look at that but I was hoping for a more "raw" solution

Comment: @PeterDickngale, this is the row solution , even you don't need to use a `$each` loop

Answer (score 0):

`<span class="section_menu_mada_page_row_name" style="">' + item.name + '</span>`

Should be

`<span class="section_menu_mada_page_row_name" style="">' ' + item.name + ' '</span>`

And the same for other places where you try to display the data